# How to create *permanent* Visual Studio Code (Insider) 'favorites' application link?

Tags: visual-studio-code, favorites

As with most applications I can **Add to Favorites** while using Visual Studio Code Insiders Edition, with

[image]

However this Favorite soon stops working and I have to resort to using the finder to find the program again, at which time I see the shortcut AND the program (the two greens - the third one (blue) is the non-insiders version!).  The first green doesn't work, the second green does work.

[image]

What I *guess* is going on here is is that VScode is updating frequently and what may be happening here is that once updated, the original shortcut point to the older version.  This does continue to work for a short while - maybe the older version is retained for a bit, but then stops working completely within a day or two.

Comment: Is this about Ubuntu? Which release?